# iOS8 Health: Steps VS Flights Climbed VS Walking+Running Distance

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app

I would like to know the exact difference between 'Steps', 'Flights Climbed' and 'Walking+Running Distance' on iOS8. While 'Flights Climbed' clearly refers to the number of flights of stairs climbed, how is it different from 'Steps', unless 'Steps' refers to the moving of the feet regardless of terrain, in which case it should be no different from 'Walking+Running Distance'. Therefore, it seems to me that there is a superfluous component, in either one of the three categories.
(Note that I refer to the manual inputting of data into the app. I believe that third-party apps would have their own way of inputting data into the app.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an iPhone 6 to be able to calculate 'flights' without any external device or manual input, as it uses a new sensor, the altimeter/air pressure sensor.

- Steps is 'how many paces you took'
- Walking/running distance is your total distance travelled - but of course paces are much longer when running.
- Flights is 'how many times did your elevation change by more than [I think] 12ft whilst you were walking.'

As far as I'm aware, 'steps' is included in 'flights', as the lateral component.
Walking up a hill will generate data for both lateral [steps] & vertical [flights] components.